# C++ Builder and TinyXML2

Tags: c++, builder, tinyxml2

Good evening,
I am using tinyXML2 for parsing my XML-Files. I am using C++ builder 10.4. from embarcadero. So my problem is. that the classes of tinyxml return text as char* Arrays. So for example:

```
AnsiString mytext = node->GetText();
```

where node is a node in my file. Unfortunately, German special characters like Ä, Ü, Ö, ß will not be translated correctly into Ansi. So I need some help.
best regards Andreas

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676169/utf-8-and-tinyxml

(I googled for [utf-8 tinyxml]).

You want to include a *minimal working example* in your question.

Comment: TinyXML2 uses UTF-8 encoded character strings. Such encoding caters for all the languages, including German. It does not create Ansi strings. You need to find out how to convert UTF-8 encoded `char*` to a suitable string class or use it as is.